# Why align environement does not work with "extract "package?

Tags: align, export

I'm using the package [`extract`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/extract) and I'm facing the following problem:

I try to extract only equation in `align` environnement (only A and not B, see the code), but it does not work. I have read the `extract` documentation but didn't find any answer. I would appreciate your help.

P.S. The code works well when there is no `align*` environement (but unfortunately I need it).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[active,
generate=test,
extract-env={align}]{extract}
\usepackage{amsthm} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

% % % %    A
\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 &= 1
\\ y &= \sqrt{1 - x^2}.
\end{align}

% % % % B               
\begin{align*}
x^2 + y^2 &= 1
\\ y &= \sqrt{1 - x^2}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

In the error log I got this message:

> \begin{align*} on input line 23 ended by \end{XTRalign}. \end{align*}

P.S. I'm wondering if it is maybe a limitation because with the `equation` environment the following code works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[active,
generate=test,
extract-env={equation}]{extract}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath} 

\begin{document}

% % % %    A
\begin{equation}
x^2 + y^2           
\end{equation}

% % % % B
\begin{equation*}
x^2 + y^2       
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It seems to be a limitation of the `extract` package.

Comment: First of all I;ve never heard for the `extract` package before, so I have no idea what it does, but the `align` construction is rather special in that AFAIR it explicitly looks for the string `\end{align}` to end it, so what ever `extract is doing may mess this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i finally find a way to overcome this limitation.

To recall the problem was the following :
-impossible to extract `align` environment using the `extract` package when there are some `align*` environment in the original file.
--> so impossible to extract only **numbered** aligned equation.

Solution :

- Replace all `align` environment by `equation` environment then add `aligned` environment ,

Concretely:

1-Search and replace all:  `\begin{align}` with `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}`

2-Search and replace all:   `\end{align}`  with `\end{aligned}\end{equation}`

And the "extract" package will works like a charm :) hope this can help,

Below the code to compare with question's code :

```
        \documentclass[a4paper]{report}

        \usepackage[ 
        active,
        generate=test,
        extract-env={equation},
        ]{extract}

        \begin{document}

        % % % %    A
        \begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
        x^2 + y^2 &= 1
        \\ y &= \sqrt{1 - x^2}.
        \end{aligned}\end{equation}

        % % % % B               
        \begin{equation*}\begin{aligned}
        x^2 + y^2 &= 1
        \\ y &= \sqrt{1 - x^2}.
        \end{aligned}\end{equation*}

        \end{document}
```